# <stdlib.h> rand() example code, unnecessary check for larger than max?

Tags: c, random, c11

I've been looking into the `int rand()` function from `<stdlib.h>` in C11 when I stumbled over the following [cppreference-example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) for rolling a six sided die.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // use current time as seed for random generator
    int random_variable = rand();
    printf("Random value on [0,%d]: %d\n", RAND_MAX, random_variable);
 
    // roll a 6-sided die 20 times
    for (int n=0; n != 20; ++n) {
        int x = 7;
        while(x > 6) 
            x = 1 + rand()/((RAND_MAX + 1u)/6); // Note: 1+rand()%6 is biased
        printf("%d ",  x); 
    }
}
```

Specifically this part:

```
[...]
        while(x > 6) 
            x = 1 + rand()/((RAND_MAX + 1u)/6); // Note: 1+rand()%6 is biased
[...]
```

Questions:

1. Why the addition of `+ 1u`? Since `rand()` is `[0,RAND_MAX]` I'm guessing
   that doing `rand()/(RAND_MAX/6) -> [0,RAND_MAX/(RAND_MAX/6)] -> [0,6]`? And
   since it's integer division `(LARGE/(LARGE+small)) < 1 -> 0`, adding `1u` gives it the required range of `[0,5]`?
2. Building on the previous question, assuming `[0,5]`, `1 + (rand()/((RAND_MAX+1u)/6))` should only go through `[1,6]` and never trigger a second loop?

Been poking around to see if `rand()` has returned `float` at some point, but
that seems like a pretty huge breakage towards old code? I guess the check
makes sense if you add `1.0f` instead of `1u` making it a floating point
division?

Trying to wrap my head around this, have a feeling that I might be missing
something..

(P.s. This is not a basis for anything security critical, I'm just exploring
the standard library. D.s)

Comment: No, `rand` has never returned a floating-point number.

Comment: "Why the addition of + 1u" How should we know? What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: The example is for rolling a six-sided dice, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: _Why the addition of + 1u_, probably intended to prevent divide-by-zero.

Comment: @ryyker but 1/6 still gives 0

Comment: rand() returns a number in the range of [0..RAND_MAX] inclusive, there are therefore RAND_MAX+1 possible values.  Why the % operator is biased is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Comment: @Lundin \*cough\* `Note: 1+rand()%6 is biased`

Comment: `while(x > 6)`?? That's going to be true for a long time, surely?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage No.  With `RAND_MAX =32767` (MSV C)  about 1 in 16k times.

Comment: "should only go through [1,6] and never trigger a second loop?" --> Pretend `RAND_MAX == 9` and walk through the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code avoids bias by ensuring each possible result in [1, 6] is the output from exactly the same number of return values from `rand`.

By definition, `rand` returns `int` values from 0 to `RAND_MAX`. So there are `1+RAND_MAX` possible values it can return. If `1+RAND_MAX` is not a multiple of 6, then it is impossible to partition it into 6 exactly equal intervals of integers. So the code partitions it into 6 equal intervals that are as big as possible and one odd-size fragment interval. Then the results of `rand` are mapped into these intervals: The first six intervals correspond to results from 1 to 6, and the last interval is rejected, and the code tries again.

When we divide `1+RAND_MAX` by 6, there is some quotient *q* and some remainder *r*. Now consider the result of `rand() / q`:

- When `rand` produces a number in [0, *q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 0.
- When `rand` produces a number in [*q*, 2*q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 1.
- When `rand` produces a number in [2*q*, 3*q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 2.
- When `rand` produces a number in [3*q*, 4*q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 3.
- When `rand` produces a number in [4*q*, 5*q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 4.
- When `rand` produces a number in [5*q*, 6*q*−1], `rand() / q` will be 5.
- When `rand` produces a number that is 6*q* or greater, `rand() / q` will be 6.

Observe that in each of the first six intervals, there are exactly *q* numbers. In the seventh interval, the possible return values are in [6*q*, `RAND_MAX`]. That interval contains *r* numbers.

This code works by rejecting that last interval:

```
int x = 7;
while(x > 6) 
    x = 1 + rand()/((RAND_MAX + 1u)/6);
```

Whenever `rand` produces a number in that last fragmentary interval, this code rejects it and tries again. When `rand` produces a number in one of the whole intervals, this code accepts it and exits (after adding 1 so the results in `x` are 1 to 6 instead of 0 to 5).

Thus, every output from 1 to 6, inclusive, is mapped to from an exactly equal number of `rand` values.

This is the best way to produce a uniform distribution from `rand` in the sense that it has the fewest rejections, given we are using a scheme like this.<sup>1</sup> The range of `rand` has been split into six intervals that are as big as possible. The remaining fragmentary interval cannot be used because the remainder *r* is less than six, so the *r* unused values cannot be split evenly over the six desired values for `x`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is not necessarily the best way to use `rand` to generate random numbers in [1, 6] overall. For example, from a single `rand` call with `RAND_MAX` equal to 32767, we could view the value as a base-six numeral from 000000 to 411411. If it is under 400000, we can take the last five digits, which are each uniformly distributed in [0, 5], and adding one gts us the desired [1, 6]. If it is in [400000, 410000), we can use the last four digits. If it is in [410000, 411000), we can use the last three, and so on. Additionally, the otherwise discarded information, such as the leading digit, might be pooled over multiple `rand` calls to increase the average number of outputs we get per call to `rand`.

Comment: I'll also note that some `rand()` implementations are known to have very poor random distributions of the lower-order bits. A straight modulo operation would result in non-random results from such a `rand()` implementation.  The bias introduced by a straight modulo implementation is probably completely insignificant in the results from a perfect `rand()` implementation as long as `RAND_MAX` is much greater than the divisor.

Comment: Ah, splendid answer! I somehow assumed that RAND_MAX was divisable by 6.. This together with @chux comment clarifies it. In summary -> `9/6 > 0.5 -> 1 != 0`. Accepted!

Comment: @GlassShark note that this probably isn't "the best way" in general, see http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html for some other ways of doing this and the various trade-offs

Comment: @SamMason Ty for the link, super interesting!